# Insufficient access when changing ldap user password

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm having an issue creating an ldap (apacheDS) user and then changing that user's password using the admin account.

I'm able to add an ldap user using the admin user:

```
# ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=mytest,dc=local -W -h ldap01.mytest.local -f /tmp/atest.ldif
adding new entry "uid=atest,cn=MyClients,ou=Users,dc=mytest,dc=local"
```

But I'm then unable to change the user's password using the same admin user:

```
# ldappasswd -x -h ldap01.mytest.local -D cn=admin,dc=mytest,dc=local -W -s Someword uid=atest,cn=MyClients,ou=Users,dc=mytest,dc=local
ber_scanf: Success
Result: Insufficient access (50)
Additional info: Non-admin user cannot access another user's password to modify it
```

Any suggestions to why or what I might be doing wrong would be welcome.